# how search a user input for a keyword in python

Tags: python, file, python-3.x, input

How  do I search a user input and find a specific keyword and then search a text file for this key word?

This is what I have so far:

```
foods = str(input("what takeaway would you like today go sir/madame reply with one word answers"))

with open("pizza.txt", "r") as f:              
    searchlines = f.readlines()

for i, line in enumerate(searchlines):      
    if foods in line:  
            print(line)
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are having?

Comment: This isn't what I asked. Please describe a *specific* problem that you have, what is the error you are getting? What is the input? What is the expected output? What is the output you are getting?

Comment: searching multiple words

Comment: @BackChat you need to show us your input, output, and describe what is wrong with the output.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Being complete and executable means (if at all possible, and it is here) that all needed data to illustrate the problem should be in the code posted.

Answer (score 0):

Your first sentence implies that you want to restrict user input to foods that might be found.  The following does this.

```
dishes = (
    "Patriot Pizza: yellow cheese, tomato, olives",
    "Tropical treat: guava cheese, pineapple, mango",
)

foods = ('cheese', 'tomato', 'olives', 'guava', 'pineapple', 'mango')
print(foods)

food = ''
while food not in foods:
    food = input('Enter one of the foods listed above: ')

for i, dish in enumerate(dishes):
    if food in dish:
        print(i, dish)
```